# Auto logon on SEAM + JSF

Tags: xml, jsf, jboss, seam

My webapp needs to auto-login when the user access the app url:

example:

```
http://myapp/home.xhtml?token={3bcdc006-05fc-4ce1-953a-17375edcf2a2}

on my pages.xml i have the following:
<pages xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages-2.1.xsd"

       no-conversation-view-id="/home.xhtml"
       login-view-id="/login.xhtml">
```

When no conversation is active the default is home.xhtml
and when the user reach the home.xhtml with a token parameter i wish that a action be called and log in the user.

any tutorial or example for that?

and if no parameter is called i wish to raise a org.jboss.seam.security.AuthorizationException so the user get redirected to error.xhtml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on page parameters in the [Seam Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5016).

In your pages.xml you would specify something like:

```
<pages>
      <page view-id="/home.xhtml" action="#{backingBean.checkToken}">
          <param name="token" value="#{backingBean.token}"/>
      </page>
</pages>
```

This will populate the variable `token` with the value from the URL and call the `checkToken()` method. In your `checkToken()` method you could check if the User is already logged in, and if not then check that the `token` has been populated, and if not then throw the `AuthorizationException`

Comment: Looking up on 2.1 docs its just what I needed, thanks for the navigation rule.

Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to question

[get-request-and-session-parameters-and-attributes-from-jsf-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550448/get-request-and-session-parameters-and-attributes-from-jsf-pages)

Some googling shows you can access request parameters using the faces context and the built in map, param, wich has your request parameters.  So, I'd sort of suggest you'd have a request bean that is loaded on the home.xhtml which checks the facesContext and raises an org.jboss.seam.security.AuthorizationException to get JBOSS to handle the login.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String requestToken = ctx.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{param.token}").getValue(ctx);
```