# How do I get and set an object in session scope in JSF?

Tags: jsf, session

I need to persist just one object in session scope of my JSF application. Where do I define a session variable, and how do I get and set it from either a view file or backing bean?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Two general ways:

- Store it in [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29)

  ```
  ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
  sessionMap.put("somekey", yourVariable);
  ```

  And then later:

  ```
  SomeObject yourVariable = (SomeObject) sessionMap.get("somekey");
  ```
- Or, make it a property of a `@SessionScoped` bean which you inject in your `@RequestScoped` bean.

  ```
  sessionBean.setSomeVariable(yourVariable);
  ```

  And then later:

  ```
  SomeObject yourVariable = sessionBean.getSomeVariable();
  ```

  You can get a `@Named @SessionScoped` into a `@Named @RequestScoped` via `@Inject`.

  ```
  @Inject
  private SessionBean sessionBean;
  ```

  Or, if you're not using CDI yet, you can get a `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` into a `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped` via `@ManagedProperty`.

  ```
  @ManagedProperty("#{sessionBean}")
  private SessionBean sessionBean; // +getter+setter
  ```

Comment: What if externalContext is null? Does something need to be configured so the client is using a session(like telling it to store a cookie)?

Comment: It's never null. And no, the session is basically already backed by a cookie. In the very rare case when the client has cookies disabled (which you **cannot** enable from the server side on), then JSF will automatically take care about URL rewriting with `jsessionid` (only when you use `<h:outputLink>`, `<h:form>` and so on instead of plain HTML `<a>`, `<form>`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Just moving along to JSF 2.2 and CDI 1.2 - Injection will at least be simpler. Keeping in line with the original answer of @BalusC:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RequestBean {
    @Inject
    private SessionBean sessionBean;
    // ...
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
      // Interact with sessionBean during construction
      // but after Injection.
    }
}
```

with

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
    private SomeObject someVariable;
    // ...
}
```

There are several important notes to be made - particularly the switch to `@Named`, and the Fully Qualified Package Name for `RequestScoped` and `SessionScoped`. Also for making a Class `SessionScoped` it should also be made `Serializable`.

The addition of `@Inject` makes it really simple - but understand that the injected `sessionBean` object is only available after construction, not during. This means you do not have access to `sessionBean` within the constructor of `RequestBean`. This is solved by the use of `@PostConstruct` which gets triggered after injection is complete, and `RequestBean` is otherwise fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` it will return the current thread but in case of P.S.V.M there will be no thread running in application context. So you get a NPE.

Better use something like this:

```
public String checker() {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from UserLogin where UserId='"
            + uid.getUserId() + "'and Pswd='" + uid.getPswd()
            + "'and RoleId='" + uid.getRoleId() + "'");
    setUid((UserLogin) q.uniqueResult());

    System.out.println("upto here every thing is workind properly");

    if (uid != null) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        HttpServletRequestrequest = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession appsession = request.getSession(true);

        if (appsession.isNew() == false) {
            appsession.invalidate();
            appsession = request.getSession(true);
        }
        context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userbean", uid);
        session.close();
        return uid.getRoleId();
    } else
        return "invalid";
}
```

and put it into a session bean. You can use the code to validate users.