# Add message to p:growl using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I want to display a growl in client-side using Javascript.

I mean this UI-component:

[image]

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730054/how-to-display-notification-with-welcome-message-when-logged-in) , However , I can't find an object called :`topBar`

Known also that using:

`grep -rl` to find text in files leads to discover this JS :

```
/**
 * PrimeFaces NotificationBar Widget
 */
PrimeFaces.widget.NotificationBar = PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({

    init: function(cfg) {
        this._super(cfg);

        var _self = this;

        //relocate
        this.jq.css(this.cfg.position, '0').appendTo($('body'));

        //display initially
        if(this.cfg.autoDisplay) {
            $(this.jq).css('display','block')
        }

        //bind events
        this.jq.children('.ui-notificationbar-close').click(function() {
            _self.hide();
        });
    },

    show: function() {
        if(this.cfg.effect === 'slide')
            $(this.jq).slideDown(this.cfg.effect);
        else if(this.cfg.effect === 'fade')
            $(this.jq).fadeIn(this.cfg.effect);
        else if(this.cfg.effect === 'none')
            $(this.jq).show();
    },

    hide: function() {
        if(this.cfg.effect === 'slide')
            $(this.jq).slideUp(this.cfg.effect);
        else if(this.cfg.effect === 'fade')
            $(this.jq).fadeOut(this.cfg.effect);
        else if(this.cfg.effect === 'none')
            $(this.jq).hide();
    },

    isVisible: function() {
        return this.jq.is(':visible');
    },

    toggle: function() {
        if(this.isVisible())
            this.hide();
        else
            this.show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The component you are referring to is Growl, in the client-side it's represented by [`PrimeFaces.widget.Growl`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.Growl.html) which has `renderMessage` function to render a single growl message.

Assuming you have already defined a growl component in your page with a widgetVar name:

```html
<p:growl widgetVar="growlWV" />
```

Now in javascript

```js
PF('growlWV').renderMessage({"summary":"summary goes here",
                             "detail":"detail goes here",
                             "severity":"warn"})
```

The severity are obviously three types :

- info

[image: info growl]

- warn

[image: warn growl]

- error

[image: error growl]

Comment: I wish this was documented properly

Comment: 'PF('growlWV').renderMessage({"summary":"summary goes here"});'
This diplaying severity type message.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the existing messages via JS?

Comment: `PF('growlWV').removeAll()` This would remove all the messages in that instance of the growl. @SeanCoetzee

Comment: `renderMessage` is private. I would use `add` https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.Growl.html#add

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me with primefaces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateSearch(){
               PF('growlWV').init({'msgs':'"summary":"Select a State Medical Unit or Demographic Capture Date", "severity":"info" ',
                   "life":"9000"})
           }

    }
```

You can see the methods here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2686099/