# How to set request attributes from a Servlet and retrieve them from a JSF (xhtml) page

Tags: jsf, servlets

I have been reading [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550448/get-request-and-session-parameters-and-attributes-from-jsf-pages) but some of the approaches suggested there don't seem to work for me. My stack is **JSF2.0** (+ PrimeFaces) and I deploy to a **JBoss 7 AS**.

There's a **Servlet** that dispatches a request to a **xhtml** page (in the same **war**) but the latter is not able to retrieve the value of the attribute set there.

Here's the Servlet code snippet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
    (...)
    request.setAttribute("foo", "foo test");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);                                    
}
```

And here's the code on the **xhtml** page:

```
<p><h:outputText value="#{sessionScope['foo']}" /></p>   
<p><h:outputText value="#{param['foo']}" /></p>                          
<p><h:outputText value="#{request.getParameter('foo')}" /></p>
```

wherein nothing shows up in any of the three cases.

What DID work was to use a backing bean (as suggested in a response to the references SO article) where the attributes are obtained in a **@PostConstruct** method as follows:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                               .getExternalContext().getRequest();
    message = (String) request.getAttribute("foo");
}
```

... where the retrieved value is subsequently available in the **xhtml** page.

But why is one method working but not the other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting an attribute in request scope in your servlet but in the xhtml page you are writing `request.getParameter("foo")` and `sessionScope['foo']` to access it.

In the xhtml page write this: `#{requestScope.foo}` and it will show the value of attribute foo.

Comment: yeap, and #{request.getAttribute('foo')} is also working .. Is anything analogous to the #{param['foo']} notation also available - but for attributes?

Comment: Sorry,I don't get it. Do you want to use '[]' notation for attributes? You can either use #{requestScope['foo']} or #{requestScope.foo} to access request scoped attributes.