# Getting Session information in EJB?

Tags: java, session, ejb

I have two questions:

- Is it good approach to get http session information in ejb?
- How can i get Http Session information in EJB tier?

**Context**

I have application in which I have two types of pages, jsp pages and jsf pages, now am getting session information in jsp page and i want to pass this session information to jsf backing bean because from backing bean am calling ejbs and needs session for setting up all remote and local interfaces for ejb.

Comment: I can add more details to the questions but wanted to first see if what am trying to do is even possible in the first place.

Comment: what are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jtahlborn: I have added more meat to the question for reference.

Comment: you have to provide more information, what you are trying to achieve? it can not be answered generally which is better and which is worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, especially since EJB's aren't usually invoked over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Session information cannot be availed from EJB's readily. However, Session being Session, you should be able to retrieve values from it, irrespective of it being a JSP or a JSF.

To retrieve a Session attribute in JSF by doing

```
<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope['id']}" />
```

Comment: More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550448/get-request-and-session-parameters-and-attributes-from-jsf-pages