# <h:outputText value="#{nameController.name}" /> doesn't print anything

Tags: java, jsf

I have written the following, very simple JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{nameController.name}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <title>Hello, <h:outputText value="#{nameController.name}" /></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello, <h:outputText value="#{nameController.name}" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `name` property of `nameController` is just an instance variable with a getter and a setter.

However, when I go to the page `http://localhost:8080/NameThing/name.xhtml?name=tbodt` (and that is the correct path to the page) I get this result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt3">
        <title>Hello, </title></head><body>
        Hello, </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place a break point in the getter, and check whether name is null? If so, the problem is not in the code you show us ...

Comment: What is the expected value of nameController.name?

Comment: @EJP As you can tell by looking at the code, it is what is passed as the GET parameter "name".

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit to a snarky version? The bounty is nice enough to post an answer anyway irrespective of your initial attitude, but the rollback is stopping me from posting it.

Comment: #{nameController.name} return an empty string (or null). Are you sure the setter is called?

Comment: Fixed your title again. You won't get anywhere by just restating your assumptions in your title, and a more precise title will lead to more precise answers. @BalusC please note.

Comment: I may have figured it out. I will try something soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out to be a bug in JSF 2.2. `<f:viewParam>` doesn't work with the new namespace. As a workaround, I changed the namespaces to this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:oldf="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Then I use `<oldf:metadata>` and `<oldf:viewParam>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass "name" by url

> ```
>    http://localhost:8080/NameThing/name.xhtml?name=tbodt.
> ```

This dont set your name property.

If you need to set your "name" property by url you have a lot of WA you can do.

1) Use javascript to set your property like BlusC describe in him blog.
[Pass variable from client side to server side](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html?microsoft#PassVariablesFromClientSideToServerSide)

2) using `<h:outputText value="#{param['name']}" />`

Like this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/550718/3056912

Answer (score -1):

How have you declared your NameController class?

When you write

```
<h:outputText value="#{nameController.name}" />
```

it's supposed to bind to the property name of a bean NameController present in the scope of the page.

So NameController should be a managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped // or RequestScoped, ApplicationScoped, etc.. (depending 
               // on how you want your bean to bean managed
public class NameController{
 // contructors
 // properties
 // getter and setter    
}
```

Comment: My bean is exactly like that, except with `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean`, and `@SessionScope` also is from CDI.

Comment: So the problem might be that you don't put any data in the NameController instance. Try to set some dumb values in the constructor and you should be able to see sth.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JBoss Weld for CDI , make sure that you added the @Model annotation or better yet a specific @Named annotation.

To narrow down the issue and distinguish between a page parameter problem and a naming problem, add a fixed string to your bean (with getters) and write it to the page.

If the string shows up its a page parameter issues, if it does not show up, its a bean naming/binding issue

Answer (score -1):

check  your Managed bean whether the class variable 'name' start with uppercase or lowercase. If it is uppercase make it lowercase and create your getter and setters again and try it again !!!

Answer (score -2):

You are using JSF 2.2 xml namespaces and obviously don't have an environment (probably an application server) which supports JSF 2.2.

If you want to use "the old" JSF 2 you have to use these namespace declarations:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

If you want to use JSF 2.2 you have to update your application server to support JSF 2.2.

Comment: If he didn't have JSF 2.2, he would have seen unparsed JSF tags in the generated HTML output. However, he got `<head>` and `<body>` instead of `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` and the `<h:outputText>` is correctly removed, it's just `#{nameController.name}` which didn't return anything.

Comment: I am using GlassFish 4. There is no way this could be.

Comment: Changing the namespace to what @unwichtich suggested solves the problem! Just tried it with no other changes! So the setup of tbodt must be wrong!

Comment: @MartinHöller It's a JSF bug.